# Facebook developer app: Unable to save Contact Email or app Domains

Tags: facebook, browser, facebook-apps, facebook-app-settings

In short, i am not able to save any information in the facebook developer app > settings > basic section. Whether it be adding a platform, updating a platform, or even adding a Contact Email or domain.

I have another FB app and its setup just fine. I have now added a second FB app and everything is setup minus this SETTINGS>BASIC tab as nothing will save. if i add a platform and do a 'quick start' tour, it will successfully add a new platform, but i am not able to make changes.

Anytime i click 'save changes', all the fields just flash then nothing happens. i have tested this in Chrome, FF and IE. All other fields in all other tabs work fine. I have gone through dozens of sites looking for an answer. Any thoughts to offer?

edit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35859147/1427878

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is some issue with the service. Developer console shows a bad request made to their basic settings service.

Comment: Thanks. I tried again this morning from a different pc on a different network, and it worked just fine. maybe it was their service? maybe something with my machine/connection? thanks