# FB developer - Cannot save changes in app settings (basic)

Tags: facebook

For a strange reason I cannot save changes in app basic settings (App Domains, Secure Page Tab URL etc). Basically - only BASIC settings do not work.
Console log:

> "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error -
>   https://developers.facebook.com/x/apps/830284910450693/settings/basic/save/?__pc=EXP1%3Adevsite_pkg"

Yesterday I was able to save changes -  today I am not.
I have googled one solution - different IPs (the app creator and mine) - nope... same IP as I can add a new app - I just cannot use the basic settings anymore... strange...

anyone?

Comment: Known bug https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1563697437290419/

Comment: oh, darn. so - the only thing for now is to wait?
Thanks, WizKid